# Why do we have a [translation] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Translation is off-topic, as has been agreed many, many times here on meta in past discussion. So why do we have a [translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag?

If there is a good reason for keeping it, please make it. I don't see one, but I suppose there exists that possibility.

If there isn't, please help go through [the open questions tagged translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btranslation%5D+closed%3A0) and either close them if they were initially missed but should have been closed, or retag them if they are not truly about translation. Once we've done that, we can delete the remaining questions that don't belong here and purge the tag.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're taking the 'translation' tag too simply as 'this is a request for translation'.

It is very appropriate to keep the 'translation' tag for questions that are motivated by a translation process, either from or to English, because that informs about the issues, how explicit the definitions and nuances must be, cultural differences. All questions on ELU are supposed to be *about* the English (directed towards the nuance of the English), but that doesn't mean that knowledge of the foreign terms and the translation process are not relevant.

So, I feel that the 'translation' tag should be kept.

Of course, closing questions for being inappropriately about translation (simply 'what is the English for the word X in language Y?') or adding additional tags is a good suggestion.

Comment: The [question about Nietzsche](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68602/what-does-backworld-mean) is a case in point. That wasn't a request for translation, in fact it was almost an anti-translation because the literal meaning makes no sense at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: well, maybe that's still in the direction that waiwai is considering. I thought that question was in the direction of off-topic (how are we supposed to know what either Nietzsche -or- the translators meant especially since they seemed to be neologisms in both languages.